# ¿Por qué no me funciona la paginación?

Tags: python, api, flask, backend, flask-restful

Estoy construyendo un backend usando python y flask como framework, ya tengo lista la Api, el servidor y ya puedo hacer el CRUD a mi Api, para consumirla estoy usando insomnia. Llego el momento de hacer paginación a mis consultas para que no me las muestre todas y no se me vaya a caer el servidor, si no que me las muestre por paginas y aquí es donde ya no me funciona, por ejemplo si quiero hacer una consulta de productos al hacer paginación ya no me funciona y me muestra este error.
[image: Error al querer separar las consultas por paginas]
[image: Este es el codigo para separar mis consultas por paginas, en este caso es de productos]

Comment: tal vez ayude https://stackoverflow.com/q/72025772/15026532

Comment: No me sirvió, no se como solucionar ese problema